# how to select and deselect all options in a select box

Tags: jquery, html

```
<select name="remaintextarea" id="studentremain" size="10">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>

<button type='button' id='selectall'>Select All</button>
<button type='button' id='deselectall'>De-Select All</button>
```

Got a select box above, select all and de-select all buttons above. My question is by using jquery, how can I get the button to select all the options and deselect all the options in the select box above when the relevant buttons are clicked on?

Below I just have the click handlers for both buttons:

```
$('#selectall').click(function() {

});   

$('#deselectall').click(function() {

});
```

Comment: You can't select all options in that element unless you add the `multiple` attribute.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to add the `multiple` attribute to the select element, and then you can:

```
$('#selectall').click(function() {
    $('select#studentremain option').attr("selected","selected");
});   

$('#deselectall').click(function() {
    $('select#studentremain option').removeAttr("selected");
});
```

Comment: @user1881090 I'm not sure because JSFiddle doesn't work for me in Chrome recently (v 23.0.1271.97), I just get loads of console errors (i.e. Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getCode'). work's perfectly  with JSFiddle on Firefox though.

Comment: @TonyDay Its ok figured it out thanks to a previous question somebody posted about same problem in SO, to deselect do this and it will unhighlight all options in chrome (works in other browsers as well) `$('select#studentremain').find("option").removeAttr("selected").end().focus().blur();`

Comment: @TonyDay: selecting and deselecting happens only once, after that there is no change  at  all, why is it  so ?

Comment: @dreamweiver Check that you haven't got an error in your JavaScript. This is usually the cause of events no longer working. Verify by adding some alerts in your code to ensure it is being reached.

Comment: @TonyDay: i havent got any errors in my jsfiddle here, but still i`m not able to select and de-select more than once ,http://jsfiddle.net/SKEL2/5/

Comment: @dreamweiver I looked at your JSFiddle and I couldn't get the event to fire even once due to the error in your selectors which should be `$('#sel')`. Then events continue to work for me however in JSFiddle so I can't see a problem. http://jsfiddle.net/SKEL2/19/

Comment: @TonyDay: sorry about that, i guess i forgot to update my jsfiddle but anyway u have corrected the selector. now if u see even after ur update i can select and deselect only once any further actions over the 'select' & 'De-Select' buttons has no response only.

Comment: @dreamweiver I don't understand what outcome you're expecting, but the events are firing again and again as indicated by the usage of alerts here http://jsfiddle.net/SKEL2/20/

Comment: @TonyDay: the events are firing successfully , but as you see that the value inside the dropdown box is not changing after one cycle of selecting and de-selecting. the value inside drop down changes only once from 1 to 3 and again from  3 to 1, any further click evets over the buttons has no effect at all :( . i hope you understood what i`m talking about

Comment: `$('select#studentremain option').removeAttr("selected");` can be written to `$('select#studentremain :selected').removeAttr("selected");` in order to run the `removeAttr` function only on proper options.

Comment: @dreamweiver.  I have the same issue like your and solve it buy using [.prop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58297515/cant-select-option-again-after-unselect/58297559?noredirect=1#comment102959007_58297559). I know it's late for 5 years, but i hoping the link can help someone in the future.

Answer (score 8):

Try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WFgdk/)

Must add multiple="multiple" in select element

HTML:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="remaintextarea" id="studentremain" size="10">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
<button type='button' id='selectall'>Select All</button>
<button type='button' id='deselectall'>De-Select All</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#selectall').click(function() {
    $('#studentremain > option').attr("selected", "selected");
});   

$('#deselectall').click(function() {
    $('#studentremain > option').removeAttr("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Somehow the answers above did not work for me. Seems that you have to use properties instead of attributes.
Here is the code:

```
$('#selectall').click(function() {
    $('select#studentremain option').prop("selected",true);
});   

$('#deselectall').click(function() {
    $('select#studentremain option').prop("selected",false);
});
```

Documentation says that `selected` attribute only specifies that an `option` should be pre-selected when the page loads. But is not set when the actual `option` is selected by the user.
[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp)

Answer (score 3):

Add the *multiple* attribute to your select box first so that you can have multiple values selected and then something like this would be sufficient since you're using jQuery.

```
//for selection of all.
$('#studentremain option').attr('selected','selected');

//for removal of selection.
$('#studentremain option').removeAttr('selected');
```

You can try *prop* and *removeProp* in the place of attr.

Answer (score 0):

> Most of the answer were outdated, 
>   Here selecting and deselecting in two different ways

```
$('#selectall').click(function() {
    $("#studentremain option").prop("selected", true);
});   

$('#deselectall').click(function() {
    $("#studentremain option").val([]);
});
```