# Can't select option again after unselect

Tags: jquery

I have an input(id=quickS) and a select(id=lbSLI_L) element like below.

[image]

My Jquery code like :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#quickS").keyup(function () {

        $("#lbSLI_L option:selected").attr('selected', false);

        $("#lbSLI_L option:contains(" + $("#quickS").val() + ")").eq(0).attr('selected', 'selected');

    });

});
```

Option text containing 1 will be selected when I type 1 in input element.

[image]

But when I delete 1 and type it again in input element, the same option won't be selected like first time.

[image]

Did I make any mistake in my code?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#quickS").keyup(function () {

        $("#lbSLI_L option:selected").removeAttr('selected');

        $("#lbSLI_L option:contains(" + $(this).val() + ")").eq(0).attr('selected', 'selected');

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="quickS" type="text" id="quickS" style="width:163px;" />
                <select size="6" name="lbSLI_L" multiple="multiple" id="lbSLI_L" style="height:90px;width:172px;">
  <option value="O/L線路斷路">1. O/L線路斷路</option>
  <option value="壓合凹陷皺褶">10. 壓合凹陷皺褶</option>
  <option value="前製程基材破裂">100. 前製程基材破裂</option>
  <option value="基材破裂(8E)">101. 基材破裂(8E)</option>
  <option value="前製程線路變細">102. 前製程線路變細</option>
  <option value="鑽孔不對位">11. 鑽孔不對位</option>
  <option value="漏鑽孔、孔未貫穿">12. 漏鑽孔、孔未貫穿</option>
  <option value="多鑽孔">13. 多鑽孔</option>
  <option value="斷鑽報廢">14. 斷鑽報廢</option>
  <option value="O/L線路缺口">17. O/L線路缺口</option>
  <option value="O/L對位不良">18. O/L對位不良</option>
  <option value="O/L外層短路">2. O/L外層短路</option>
  <option value="O/L銅殘留">20. O/L銅殘留</option>
  <option value="Pad破損">22. Pad破損</option>
  <option value="線路刮撞傷">23. 線路刮撞傷</option>
  <option value="修補O/L蝕刻不全">25. 修補O/L蝕刻不全</option>
  <option value="修補線路刮撞傷">29. 修補線路刮撞傷</option>
  <option value="基材破裂">3. 基材破裂</option>
  <option value="修補顯影刮撞傷">30. 修補顯影刮撞傷</option>
  <option value="顯影刮撞傷">32. 顯影刮撞傷</option>
  <option value="O/L線路斷路(共同性)">33. O/L線路斷路(共同性)</option>
  <option value="O/L外層短路(共同性)">34. O/L外層短路(共同性)</option>
  <option value="O/L線路缺口(共同性)">35. O/L線路缺口(共同性)</option>
  <option value="O/L銅殘留(共同性)">36. O/L銅殘留(共同性)</option>
  <option value="孔內結瘤">37. 孔內結瘤</option>
  <option value="顯影刮撞傷(集中區域)">38. 顯影刮撞傷(集中區域)</option>
  <option value="修補O/L外層短路(共同性)">39. 修補O/L外層短路(共同性)</option>
  <option value="AOS">4. AOS</option>
  <option value="修補O/L銅殘留(共同性)">40. 修補O/L銅殘留(共同性)</option>
  <option value="修補夾膜殘銅">41. 修補夾膜殘銅</option>
  <option value="修補顯影刮撞傷(集中區域)">42. 修補顯影刮撞傷(集中區域)</option>
  <option value="修補滲鍍">43. 修補滲鍍</option>
  <option value="修補O/L外層短路">44. 修補O/L外層短路</option>
  <option value="修補O/L銅殘留">45. 修補O/L銅殘留</option>
  <option value="O/L線路變細">46. O/L線路變細</option>
  <option value="結瘤(SHORT)">47. 結瘤(SHORT)</option>
  <option value="乾膜浮(剝)離">48. 乾膜浮(剝)離</option>
  <option value="線路分層">49. 線路分層</option>
  <option value="凹陷">5. 凹陷</option>
  <option value="內層紅筆報廢">50. 內層紅筆報廢</option>
  <option value="PTH壓傷">51. PTH壓傷</option>
  <option value="異物抗鍍">52. 異物抗鍍</option>
  <option value="外層前刮傷">53. 外層前刮傷</option>
  <option value="填孔不良">55. 填孔不良</option>
  <option value="乾膜殘留">56. 乾膜殘留</option>
  <option value="棕化不良">57. 棕化不良</option>
  <option value="壓合氣泡">58. 壓合氣泡</option>
  <option value="異物抗咬蝕">59. 異物抗咬蝕</option>
  <option value="夾膜殘銅">6. 夾膜殘銅</option>
  <option value="底銅抗咬蝕">60. 底銅抗咬蝕</option>
  <option value="藥液殘留(72)">62. 藥液殘留(72)</option>
  <option value="內層紅筆劃超出">63. 內層紅筆劃超出</option>
  <option value="孔銅斜角">64. 孔銅斜角</option>
  <option value="等高殘銅">66. 等高殘銅</option>
  <option value="光點不見/破損">67. 光點不見/破損</option>
  <option value="樹脂灌孔不良">68. 樹脂灌孔不良</option>
  <option value="修補異物抗咬蝕">69. 修補異物抗咬蝕</option>
  <option value="滲鍍">7. 滲鍍</option>
  <option value="修補底銅抗咬蝕">70. 修補底銅抗咬蝕</option>
  <option value="修補等高殘銅">71. 修補等高殘銅</option>
  <option value="板面氧化污染(68)">72. 板面氧化污染(68)</option>
  <option value="修補結瘤(SHORT)">73. 修補結瘤(SHORT)</option>
  <option value="破孔(29)">74. 破孔(29)</option>
  <option value="黑色異物">75. 黑色異物</option>
  <option value="玻纖異常">76. 玻纖異常</option>
  <option value="板面殘膠污染(68)">77. 板面殘膠污染(68)</option>
  <option value="線路錯位(4D)">78. 線路錯位(4D)</option>
  <option value="線路刮撞傷-剝離(89)">79. 線路刮撞傷-剝離(89)</option>
  <option value="O/L蝕刻不全">8. O/L蝕刻不全</option>
  <option value="其他.">80. 其他.</option>
  <option value="其他.">81. 其他.</option>
  <option value="其他">82. 其他</option>
  <option value="孔位偏移">9. 孔位偏移</option>
  <option value="前製程基材破裂">98. 前製程基材破裂</option>
  <option value="切片">99. 切片</option>
  <option value="未定義劃記報廢">UN. 未定義劃記報廢</option>

 </select>
```

Comment: use `$(selector).prop(property,value)` instead `attr` .this will help you [jQuery prop() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_prop.asp)

Comment: Prop won't help, actually. I think you have found some kind of bug

Comment: I found a [document](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) pointed out: **To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method. The attribute actually corresponds to the defaultChecked property and should be used only to set the initial value of the checkbox. The checked attribute value does not change with the state of the checkbox, while the checked property does.** I guess this is why `attr` can only select option one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with remove selected property as shown below and set the property of matching option and use `$(this)` to read value of input box instead of selecting it again by id as this will improve the performance

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#quickS").keyup(function () {

        $("#lbSLI_L option:selected").removeProp('selected');

        $("#lbSLI_L option:contains(" + $(this).val() + ")").eq(0).prop('selected', 'selected');

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="quickS" type="text" id="quickS" style="width:163px;" />
                <select size="6" name="lbSLI_L" multiple="multiple" id="lbSLI_L" style="height:90px;width:172px;">
  <option value="O/L線路斷路">1. O/L線路斷路</option>
  <option value="壓合凹陷皺褶">10. 壓合凹陷皺褶</option>
  <option value="前製程基材破裂">100. 前製程基材破裂</option>
  <option value="基材破裂(8E)">101. 基材破裂(8E)</option>
  <option value="前製程線路變細">102. 前製程線路變細</option>
  <option value="鑽孔不對位">11. 鑽孔不對位</option>
  <option value="漏鑽孔、孔未貫穿">12. 漏鑽孔、孔未貫穿</option>
  <option value="多鑽孔">13. 多鑽孔</option>
  <option value="斷鑽報廢">14. 斷鑽報廢</option>
  <option value="O/L線路缺口">17. O/L線路缺口</option>
  <option value="O/L對位不良">18. O/L對位不良</option>
  <option value="O/L外層短路">2. O/L外層短路</option>
  <option value="O/L銅殘留">20. O/L銅殘留</option>
  <option value="Pad破損">22. Pad破損</option>
  <option value="線路刮撞傷">23. 線路刮撞傷</option>
  <option value="修補O/L蝕刻不全">25. 修補O/L蝕刻不全</option>
  <option value="修補線路刮撞傷">29. 修補線路刮撞傷</option>
  <option value="基材破裂">3. 基材破裂</option>
  <option value="修補顯影刮撞傷">30. 修補顯影刮撞傷</option>
  <option value="顯影刮撞傷">32. 顯影刮撞傷</option>
  <option value="O/L線路斷路(共同性)">33. O/L線路斷路(共同性)</option>
  <option value="O/L外層短路(共同性)">34. O/L外層短路(共同性)</option>
  <option value="O/L線路缺口(共同性)">35. O/L線路缺口(共同性)</option>
  <option value="O/L銅殘留(共同性)">36. O/L銅殘留(共同性)</option>
  <option value="孔內結瘤">37. 孔內結瘤</option>
  <option value="顯影刮撞傷(集中區域)">38. 顯影刮撞傷(集中區域)</option>
  <option value="修補O/L外層短路(共同性)">39. 修補O/L外層短路(共同性)</option>
  <option value="AOS">4. AOS</option>
  <option value="修補O/L銅殘留(共同性)">40. 修補O/L銅殘留(共同性)</option>
  <option value="修補夾膜殘銅">41. 修補夾膜殘銅</option>
  <option value="修補顯影刮撞傷(集中區域)">42. 修補顯影刮撞傷(集中區域)</option>
  <option value="修補滲鍍">43. 修補滲鍍</option>
  <option value="修補O/L外層短路">44. 修補O/L外層短路</option>
  <option value="修補O/L銅殘留">45. 修補O/L銅殘留</option>
  <option value="O/L線路變細">46. O/L線路變細</option>
  <option value="結瘤(SHORT)">47. 結瘤(SHORT)</option>
  <option value="乾膜浮(剝)離">48. 乾膜浮(剝)離</option>
  <option value="線路分層">49. 線路分層</option>
  <option value="凹陷">5. 凹陷</option>
  <option value="內層紅筆報廢">50. 內層紅筆報廢</option>
  <option value="PTH壓傷">51. PTH壓傷</option>
  <option value="異物抗鍍">52. 異物抗鍍</option>
  <option value="外層前刮傷">53. 外層前刮傷</option>
  <option value="填孔不良">55. 填孔不良</option>
  <option value="乾膜殘留">56. 乾膜殘留</option>
  <option value="棕化不良">57. 棕化不良</option>
  <option value="壓合氣泡">58. 壓合氣泡</option>
  <option value="異物抗咬蝕">59. 異物抗咬蝕</option>
  <option value="夾膜殘銅">6. 夾膜殘銅</option>
  <option value="底銅抗咬蝕">60. 底銅抗咬蝕</option>
  <option value="藥液殘留(72)">62. 藥液殘留(72)</option>
  <option value="內層紅筆劃超出">63. 內層紅筆劃超出</option>
  <option value="孔銅斜角">64. 孔銅斜角</option>
  <option value="等高殘銅">66. 等高殘銅</option>
  <option value="光點不見/破損">67. 光點不見/破損</option>
  <option value="樹脂灌孔不良">68. 樹脂灌孔不良</option>
  <option value="修補異物抗咬蝕">69. 修補異物抗咬蝕</option>
  <option value="滲鍍">7. 滲鍍</option>
  <option value="修補底銅抗咬蝕">70. 修補底銅抗咬蝕</option>
  <option value="修補等高殘銅">71. 修補等高殘銅</option>
  <option value="板面氧化污染(68)">72. 板面氧化污染(68)</option>
  <option value="修補結瘤(SHORT)">73. 修補結瘤(SHORT)</option>
  <option value="破孔(29)">74. 破孔(29)</option>
  <option value="黑色異物">75. 黑色異物</option>
  <option value="玻纖異常">76. 玻纖異常</option>
  <option value="板面殘膠污染(68)">77. 板面殘膠污染(68)</option>
  <option value="線路錯位(4D)">78. 線路錯位(4D)</option>
  <option value="線路刮撞傷-剝離(89)">79. 線路刮撞傷-剝離(89)</option>
  <option value="O/L蝕刻不全">8. O/L蝕刻不全</option>
  <option value="其他.">80. 其他.</option>
  <option value="其他.">81. 其他.</option>
  <option value="其他">82. 其他</option>
  <option value="孔位偏移">9. 孔位偏移</option>
  <option value="前製程基材破裂">98. 前製程基材破裂</option>
  <option value="切片">99. 切片</option>
  <option value="未定義劃記報廢">UN. 未定義劃記報廢</option>

 </select>
```

Comment: The situation still happen. But thank for performance advice.

Comment: can you reproduce the issue on code snippet or on jsfiddle so that i can take a look at it

Comment: Please check my updated post using `removeProp` and `prop`

Comment: Your code does not work in Chrome. It does not even unhighlight when I delete 1

Comment: @mplungjan. This working fine.  This is my fault that it does not  unhighlight when you delete 1, because i have space in option text. I have added  if-condition in my code to prevent it now.

Comment: Why would a space make a change? My code works with your HTML

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue with select multiple and not using .prop

Just don't select if there is no value

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#quickS").on("input", function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#lbSLI_L option:selected").prop('selected', false);
    if (val !== "") $("#lbSLI_L option:contains(" + val + ")").eq(0).prop('selected', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="quickS" type="text" id="quickS" style="width:163px;" />
<select size="6" name="lbSLI_L" multiple="multiple" id="lbSLI_L" style="height:90px;width:172px;">
  <option value="O/L線路斷路">1. O/L線路斷路</option>
  <option value="壓合凹陷皺褶">10. 壓合凹陷皺褶</option>
  <option value="前製程基材破裂">100. 前製程基材破裂</option>
  <option value="基材破裂(8E)">101. 基材破裂(8E)</option>
  <option value="前製程線路變細">102. 前製程線路變細</option>
  <option value="鑽孔不對位">11. 鑽孔不對位</option>
  <option value="漏鑽孔、孔未貫穿">12. 漏鑽孔、孔未貫穿</option>
  <option value="多鑽孔">13. 多鑽孔</option>
  <option value="斷鑽報廢">14. 斷鑽報廢</option>
  <option value="O/L線路缺口">17. O/L線路缺口</option>
  <option value="O/L對位不良">18. O/L對位不良</option>
  <option value="O/L外層短路">2. O/L外層短路</option>
  <option value="O/L銅殘留">20. O/L銅殘留</option>
  <option value="Pad破損">22. Pad破損</option>
  <option value="線路刮撞傷">23. 線路刮撞傷</option>
  <option value="修補O/L蝕刻不全">25. 修補O/L蝕刻不全</option>
  <option value="修補線路刮撞傷">29. 修補線路刮撞傷</option>
  <option value="基材破裂">3. 基材破裂</option>
  <option value="修補顯影刮撞傷">30. 修補顯影刮撞傷</option>
  <option value="顯影刮撞傷">32. 顯影刮撞傷</option>
  <option value="O/L線路斷路(共同性)">33. O/L線路斷路(共同性)</option>
  <option value="O/L外層短路(共同性)">34. O/L外層短路(共同性)</option>
  <option value="O/L線路缺口(共同性)">35. O/L線路缺口(共同性)</option>
  <option value="O/L銅殘留(共同性)">36. O/L銅殘留(共同性)</option>
  <option value="孔內結瘤">37. 孔內結瘤</option>
  <option value="顯影刮撞傷(集中區域)">38. 顯影刮撞傷(集中區域)</option>
  <option value="修補O/L外層短路(共同性)">39. 修補O/L外層短路(共同性)</option>
  <option value="AOS">4. AOS</option>
  <option value="修補O/L銅殘留(共同性)">40. 修補O/L銅殘留(共同性)</option>
  <option value="修補夾膜殘銅">41. 修補夾膜殘銅</option>
  <option value="修補顯影刮撞傷(集中區域)">42. 修補顯影刮撞傷(集中區域)</option>
  <option value="修補滲鍍">43. 修補滲鍍</option>
  <option value="修補O/L外層短路">44. 修補O/L外層短路</option>
  <option value="修補O/L銅殘留">45. 修補O/L銅殘留</option>
  <option value="O/L線路變細">46. O/L線路變細</option>
  <option value="結瘤(SHORT)">47. 結瘤(SHORT)</option>
  <option value="乾膜浮(剝)離">48. 乾膜浮(剝)離</option>
  <option value="線路分層">49. 線路分層</option>
  <option value="凹陷">5. 凹陷</option>
  <option value="內層紅筆報廢">50. 內層紅筆報廢</option>
  <option value="PTH壓傷">51. PTH壓傷</option>
  <option value="異物抗鍍">52. 異物抗鍍</option>
  <option value="外層前刮傷">53. 外層前刮傷</option>
  <option value="填孔不良">55. 填孔不良</option>
  <option value="乾膜殘留">56. 乾膜殘留</option>
  <option value="棕化不良">57. 棕化不良</option>
  <option value="壓合氣泡">58. 壓合氣泡</option>
  <option value="異物抗咬蝕">59. 異物抗咬蝕</option>
  <option value="夾膜殘銅">6. 夾膜殘銅</option>
  <option value="底銅抗咬蝕">60. 底銅抗咬蝕</option>
  <option value="藥液殘留(72)">62. 藥液殘留(72)</option>
  <option value="內層紅筆劃超出">63. 內層紅筆劃超出</option>
  <option value="孔銅斜角">64. 孔銅斜角</option>
  <option value="等高殘銅">66. 等高殘銅</option>
  <option value="光點不見/破損">67. 光點不見/破損</option>
  <option value="樹脂灌孔不良">68. 樹脂灌孔不良</option>
  <option value="修補異物抗咬蝕">69. 修補異物抗咬蝕</option>
  <option value="滲鍍">7. 滲鍍</option>
  <option value="修補底銅抗咬蝕">70. 修補底銅抗咬蝕</option>
  <option value="修補等高殘銅">71. 修補等高殘銅</option>
  <option value="板面氧化污染(68)">72. 板面氧化污染(68)</option>
  <option value="修補結瘤(SHORT)">73. 修補結瘤(SHORT)</option>
  <option value="破孔(29)">74. 破孔(29)</option>
  <option value="黑色異物">75. 黑色異物</option>
  <option value="玻纖異常">76. 玻纖異常</option>
  <option value="板面殘膠污染(68)">77. 板面殘膠污染(68)</option>
  <option value="線路錯位(4D)">78. 線路錯位(4D)</option>
  <option value="線路刮撞傷-剝離(89)">79. 線路刮撞傷-剝離(89)</option>
  <option value="O/L蝕刻不全">8. O/L蝕刻不全</option>
  <option value="其他.">80. 其他.</option>
  <option value="其他.">81. 其他.</option>
  <option value="其他">82. 其他</option>
  <option value="孔位偏移">9. 孔位偏移</option>
  <option value="前製程基材破裂">98. 前製程基材破裂</option>
  <option value="切片">99. 切片</option>
  <option value="未定義劃記報廢">UN. 未定義劃記報廢</option>

</select>
```